# Python - Get the url after redirection

Tags: python, proxy, oauth-2.0, http-redirect

**For those who know about the SE API**
I am making a wrapper for the SE API.
The trouble is I don't own a server or website, so I cannot have a `redirect_uri` to my website.

I figured that I can use `stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`.
I've also realized that after the user authenticates themselves, if the same page is opened again, I am redirected to the `redirect_uri`.

How can I get the URL I am redirected to???

> **For Those who don't know about the SE API**
>   Consider this:
>
> 1. I go to link1 say, xyz.com/abc?a=10&b=20
> 2. It redirects me to link2 (`abc.com/xyz?add=30&mul=200`)
>
> I want to get the URL of link2.

Also,
I am behind a proxy, so am using an opener for handling the proxy. (In case that matters)

I am using `urllib2`, so would prefer a solution that uses the same, but please limit your answers to in-built libraries

Comment: there are different ways to redirect a user. what is the contents of an HTTP reply that you get from SE API? if they're using HTTP 3xx redirects then the header should have a "Location:" field containing the URL.

Comment: @CaptSolo Yay!! someone commented!!! Jokes apart, How do I get the HTTP reply of the API?? I've seen the (1) of the first example [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html), but it doesn't work.

Comment: in order to debug the problem you might try the Requests ( http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ ) library which claims to be more helpful than urllib2. -- it breaks your "only built-in libraries" requirement, but once you understand the problem you can reimplement the solution using e.g. urllib2.

Answer (score 0):

What if you set up a simple local server? You could, for example use Flask. Also if you just want to consume the StackExchange API, you could use a prebuilt client, e.g. rauth might do exactly what you want. If you want to setup a simple server and run it locally have a look at the rauth [Facebook login example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples/facebook). Then what you'd do is redirect to your localhost, e.g. the authorized view in that example:

```
def login():
    # this will map to your local server
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorized', _external=True)

    params = {'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}
    return redirect(facebook.get_authorize_url(**params)
```

Full disclosure, I maintain rauth.